# Change the color of the setup frame

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to change the color of the setup frame, in this case from gray to white. (or vice versa)
For clarity an example:

[image: Screenshot Setup]

Thank you for your time,
Alexei

Comment: Please add your image properly, using the toolbar button for adding a graphic. Links to off-site locations other than the officially supported Imgur are not acceptable.

Comment: Done, thanks for the RE
Alexei

Comment: Why not add your answer as an answer instead of editing the question?

Comment: Andrew Truckle. Sorry, my mistake, I am not so good with using the forum, I promise to improve my use of the forum by first carefully studying the rules.
Thank you for using the knowledge on this great furum.
Alexei

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with:

```
WizardForm.Color := clWhite;
```

After a lot of searching I found this on this great forum. Thanks for thinking along and answering.